# Microsoft Outlook 2010, add specific reply signature based on email domain?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is it possible to create a rule that adds a specific reply signature based on email domain?

I.e. I receive a question from `john.smith@client1.com`.
When I reply to the message the signature should be a specific (perhaps have 10 different signatures) based on the domain "client1.com"
For "client2.com" there should be a different signature and so on.
Perhaps you can do this by with VBA code?

Comment: There is no built-in option available in Outlook to automatically select signature based on domain. Apart from using VBA code, if you are using Exchange account, you can also contact your Exchange administrator to set up transport rule to append disclaimer automatically based on the keywords in recipients' email addresses.